# R8 ignores ProGuard option "useuniqueclassmembernames". Alternatives?

Tags: android, optimization, proguard, obfuscation, android-r8

At some point in the past ProGuard seemed to ignore the rule "useuniqueclassmembernames" making it almost impossible for me to read stack traces of crashes my app users encountered. I just happened to learn now, that at some point they swapped ProGuard with R8, which is now the standard optimizer/obfuscator (please correct me if I am wrong). The unofficial R8 documentation (https://r8-docs.preemptive.com/) states that several ProGuard rules are being ignored

```
The following rules are ignored:

-addconfigurationdebugging
-android
-assumenoescapingparameters
-assumenoexternalreturnvalues
-assumenoexternalsideefffects
-dontpreverify
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dump
-forceprocessing
-keepparameternames
-mergeinterfacesaggressively
-outjars
-target
-useuniqueclassmembernames
-verbose
```

This is causing a lot of troubles for me. As a workaround I am now using the option of

> android.enableR8=false

which is being flagged as deprecated and not recommended.

Is there any way to have the effect of useuniqueclassmembernames using R8?

Comment: While this does not answer your question, an alternative is to continue using Proguard, which is being maintained and developed. For that indeed you have to set enableR8 to false (https://www.guardsquare.com/en/blog/comparison-proguard-vs-r8-october-2019-edition).

Comment: Is there any particular reason not to use ReTrace (with mapping files) to deobfuscate the stack trace?